# Eclipse ADT error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to open eclipse adt, but shows me an error, and i went to the log.

I tried to notice something, and i could reach to the solution.

here is the log.

> 

```
    !SESSION 2014-03-31 08:36:03.065 -----------------------------------------------
>     eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
>     java.version=1.7.0_45
>     java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>     BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=pt_BR
>     Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>     Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>     
>     !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-03-31 08:36:03.505
>     !MESSAGE Startup error
>     !STACK 1
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
> of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
>     Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
> of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
>       ... 11 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/eclipse/osgi/internal/module/ResolverImpl.class
>       at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.createResolver(StateManager.java:283)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.initializeSystemState(StateManager.java:182)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.createSystemState(StateManager.java:195)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readStateData(BaseStorage.java:835)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:791)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:915)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>       ... 13
```

I seens to be java error, no?
I'm using fedora 19, installed open-jdk-1.7 and 1.8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Android fully support JDK v1.7 or later yet. So, you will need to download and install JDK v1.6.45.

You can get JDK v1.6.45 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR).

Comment: i installed jdk 1.6.45 and i had a problem while using autocomplete.
here is the log http://codepad.org/ZWjaFvl5

Comment: Make sure you download the correct 32-bit or 64-bit JDK v6 for your operating system. If you have done this and getting the error about autocomplete, then please log a [bug report](http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp) with Oracle.

Comment: i downloaded the correct version, i will report bug. Thanks.