# eclipse was started but returned exit code=1073740791

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I'm new in android (and english!). I downloaded last version of android SDK. some info about versions:
ADT: v22.6.2-1085508  /  Eclipse java development tools: 3.9.1.v20130911-1000 / JDK: 7u51-windows-x64 / 
also I recently installed win8.1 . I could run the eclipse. but when i tried to build a new android application it returned the error above. I set minimum required SDK on API10 and target SDK on API19 and leave other fields as default. at the first a dialog box appear with this message: java(TM) platform SE binary has stopped working. then the one with "Eclipse" title appear. and here the dialog box: ([+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvgIF.jpg))

please tell me if you know how can i fix it. thank in advance

Comment: I have answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761236/eclipse-adt-error/22761555#22761555).

Comment: so weird, reinstall the eclipse.